# Plain URL stops hyperlinking at marking characters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

When posting [an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/180079/revisions), I wrote the following text

> ```
> Remove that lowercase "m" in https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png
>                                                             ^ ^
> ```

And it ended up as

> Remove that lowercase "m" in https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png

However it was supposed to be

> Remove that lowercase "m" in [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXXm.png)

You see, the plain URL was cut off at the first asterisk, which wasn't a display character, but a marking character (for italic). It shouldn't have been cut at the asterisk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, yeah that's how URLs work. You italicized something in the link so it was no long a part of the link. If you want to apply formatting to the text that displays without breaking the link, you have to use a different syntax to do it:

```
Remove that lowercase m in [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXXm.png)
```

> Remove that lowercase m in [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXXm.png)

Think of it this way... that link can be processed one of two ways:

1. Linkify first, and then process the italics, which would result in this:

   ```
   <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png">https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX<i>m</i>.png</a>
   ```

   That's clearly wrong. Now you have asterisks in the actual URL.
2. Process italics first, then linkify, which would result in this:

   ```
   <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX<i>m</i>.png">https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX<i>m</i>.png</a>
   ```

   That's clearly wrong, because it makes the HTML completely invalid.

The system doesn't strip out the Markdown to try and determine what additional formatting might apply if other formatting didn't exist. You're asking the system to do too much.

Comment: Why can't the system filter out plain texts? Like I do when I drag my mouse to select some text and copy-paste, then all marking attributes are lost.

Comment: @iBug That's actually not what happens. You do actually copy the text with all the formatting still applied to it. Different programs choose what to do with that text when you *paste* it. E.g. when you paste it back into a textarea in your browser that doesn't support formatting out of the box, it removes all the formatting from the text because it can't be displayed there. If you paste it into something like Microsoft Word, the formatting is preserved.

Comment: Anyways, that's a completely different feature. Trying to predict what the user wants to do is not a responsibility of Markdown. The user needs to be explicit in how they want something rendered. Markdown is a specification of "this happens when this is present" type of stuff.